# Notification is not canceling after click the notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm sending notification when device is in background. The notification is sending to the user mobile. but after clicking the notification it's not cancelling. Still showing in the statusbar. I'm using this for iBeacon send notification. But i think, i need to check the deivce is foregraound or background.If it's  foreground we have to cancel the notification. If background we need to send notification. How can we check this?

```
 Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(NotifyDemoActivity.this, NotifyDemoActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
        NotifyDemoActivity.this,
        0,
        new Intent[]{notifyIntent},
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


   // Intent showIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyDemoActivity.class);
   // PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, showIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(NotifyDemoActivity.this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray)
        .setContentTitle("Welcome")
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: On which device/platform are you testing?

Comment: You are missing the PendingIntent it seems.